# Use Laravel Socialite register user and redirect to form to fill out more data?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, eloquent, laravel-socialite

I have implemented Laravel Socialite with Google today as described in [this article](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-7-6-google-login-tutorial-with-socialite-demo-example/). So far so good, everything is working.

However, I want to do a few changes and customize the process of registering users who login the first time via social networks. My Laravel project is working with nicknames like in forums. Of course these nicknames have to be unique.

My goal is now to redirect users who login via social networks for the first time to a form where they can enter a nickname and when this form gets submitted the user gets created. I am a little bit screwed on how I am going to implement this and need your advice.

The problem is, I have to fetch the data from e.g. Google, redirect the user to a form where he enters his nickname and submits the form. But this form has to include all data, also the data which I got from Google in order to create a user with nickname, email, avatar, provider (e.g. google, facebook, etc.) and provider id.

I haven't pasted any code here now because my code looks exactly the same as described in the article above I linked!

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the kind of set up you have but am going to give a very opinionated suggestion, plus am going to answer this with the assumption your not new to laravel.

1. When the response comes from the third party through socialite you have to store the info in the session to avoid losing the data if the user refreshes their browser, this should be set to expire in a very short period of time.
2. You're going to need a middleware that will redirect to the registration completion form where the user will provide their nickname if the key used to store the user data received from Socialite is set in the session. This should behave exactly like the laravel's verify email middleware to make sure the user doesn't access any other part of the website if the registration process is active.
3. After the user fills out this form and submits it, you can now validate their input, retrieve the Socialite data from the session, and then create the user as you see fit. As soon as your done don't forget to remove the data from session to avoid activating the middleware.